# jQuery string comparison behaves differently in IE7

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-7, cross-browser

The following snippet is used in conjunction with a jQuery UI autocomplete element (`#search`). In Firefox, Chrome, etc. it behaves as expected and always returns true for the selected element. **In Internet Explorer 7 it doesn't**.

```
$('mySelector').filter(function() {
    if ($(this).text().toLowerCase() == $('#search').val().toLowerCase()) {
         return true;
    }
});
```

For any hints about how this behaviour could be caused I will be very thankful!

**EDIT:** After pasting the nice analyze function by Šime Vidas I run the thing again and here comes the result of the comparison that should return true:

[image]

After some more investigation. I seems the comparison returns true (thank god, otherwise I would have needed a shrink). But the filter function return any valid objects. Which it should, if the comparison is true.

**EDIT:** Turns out I tested only cases where everything was fine. A few entries had double spaces between first and last name which didn't result in a FALSE evaluation in FF and Chrome but did in IE7.

Comment: Well, obviously what you have to do is log (or alert) both operands of the `==` operation. Then you'll know why the operation evaluates to false in IE7.

Comment: That's what I did. I didn't see any difference between the two strings, when the selected element was compared to the list. The difference must be hidden. I'd send to console but since I'm in IE7 I obviously can't use firebug and I didn't find a way yet to easily log to console in IE7.

Comment: So you placed both strings into variables, ran `analyze()` for both of them, and stil `str1 == str2` evaluates to false in IE7?

Comment: @ŠimeVidas Actually, as I just edited into my question. It does return true. Do'h. It must. But this somehow doesn't trigger the filter to return.

Comment: I don't know it this is relevant for this issue, but usually you want to put `return false;` after the if-statement (to cover both  cases). If you don't do that, `undefined` will be returned, and I'm not sure how `filter` acts in that case.

Comment: Thanks for thinking along. `return false;` didn't help either. I have no clue what's going on...

Comment: How many elements does `$('mySelector')` initially capture? How many elements "survive" the `filter` method? Same questions for IE7.

Comment: Yes, that's the next thing to investigate. Theoretically there should always be exactly one and only one element filtered. I store it and use it further like that: `filteredObject = $('ul.myclass li').filter(function()[...]`. The problem might be that I'm directly using the filteredObject later on and most browsers don't mind but IE does. How would I extract the first element out of a collection? In PHP I would for example do reset($array) to get the first element.

Comment: Use `filteredObject.length` to see how many elements are in there. Use `filteredObject[0]` to get the first element. So there is only one LI element inside your UL.myClass?

Comment: No there are many li elements but the filter should only return true once. Sometimes I get this `Error Message: 'parent().attr(...)' is null or not an object` which obviously comes from the fact that the filteredObject is empty or the wrong type or smth.

Comment: But it's even more confused because sometimes the filter also doesn't find anything. I'm not sure maybe it also has to do with special chars (éè...).

Comment: `var test = $('ul.myclass li');`. Check `test.length` in both IE7 and another brower. Is it the same number? Now: `test.filter(...);`. After that check `test.length` again. Is it 1 in both browsers?

Comment: I'll do that, thanks a lot, I'll keep you posted.

Comment: Again also these tests result in exactly the same for IE7 and other browsers. 414 elements first, and 1 element after filtering.

Comment: But on irregular occasions I get `undefined` instead of 1 after the filtering. Totally irregular it seems.

Comment: `undefined`? What is undefined, the jQuery object itself or its `length` property?

Comment: One part of the problem is solved. Turns out some of the names had two spaces between them instead of one. In all other browsers, the li elements would be identical with the search (both two spaces) but in IE7, the space would be somehow magically stripped away in the li tag but not in the search. After trimming everything before rendering, I don't get any undefined errors anymore.

Comment: `test.length` resulted in undefined. But only in those cases where the double spaces between first and last name were present and only in IE7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here:

```
function analyze( str ) {
    var output, i;

    output = 'String: ' + str + ' - Length: ' + str.length + '; ';

    for ( i = 0; i < str.length; i += 1 ) {
        output += str.charCodeAt( i ) + ' ';
    }

    return output;  
}
```

And then:

```
alert( analyze( operand1 ) + '\n\n' + analyze( operand2 ) );
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/jsZzY/

The alert box will show you all code points of both strings....

Comment: I just added a little improvement so it's also possible to see the string itself. The crazy part in my original question.

Comment: This together with all the hints in the discussion (above) deserves the accepted answer, even though the issue is more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe `$(this).text()` in IE7 returns some additional chars. For example extra spaces, new lines (`\r\n`) etc. Try to output `$(this).text()` and `$('#search').val()` and visual compare this two strings.

Also you can try to add `jQuery.trim` functions, etc. If you rid out from all garbage your code should work.

Comment: I visually compared already and there is no different. In fact the real version also has the $.trim() wrapped around both which also didn't change anything.

Comment: Output something like `"**" + value + "**"` that way you can see if there are spaces/CRs/tabs/misc before/after the values.